# Automatic labelling of newly created indicator variables in Stata

Tags: stata

I have a variable called `region`, which has 22 elements. Here is the output of `tabulate region`:

```
   region of place of work |      Freq.     Percent        Cum.
---------------------------+-----------------------------------
               tyne & wear |          6        1.20        1.20
   rest of northern region |         12        2.40        3.60
           south yorkshire |          9        1.80        5.40
            west yorkshire |         23        4.60       10.00
rest of yorks & humberside |          9        1.80       11.80
             east midlands |         42        8.40       20.20
               east anglia |         12        2.40       22.60
            central london |         41        8.20       30.80
inner london (not central) |         23        4.60       35.40
              outer london |         19        3.80       39.20
        rest of south east |         97       19.40       58.60
                south west |         46        9.20       67.80
west midlands metropolitan |         29        5.80       73.60
     rest of west midlands |         14        2.80       76.40
        greater manchester |         15        3.00       79.40
                merseyside |          2        0.40       79.80
        rest of north west |         31        6.20       86.00
                     wales |         12        2.40       88.40
               strathclyde |         23        4.60       93.00
          rest of scotland |         27        5.40       98.40
          northern ireland |          8        1.60      100.00
---------------------------+-----------------------------------
                     Total |        500      100.00
```

I have created indicator variables from it using `tab region, gen(region_)`. This creates 22 new variables, from `region_1` to `region_22`. I **do want** the indicator variables to have simple names like `region_1`, etc (e.g. they are more easy to call using `region_*`). The problem is the **label of the variable**, which is something like `region==south west`. I want it to be `south west`.

I have looked at `dummieslab` (SSC) but it focuses on adding labels to the new variable **names**. None of [these](http://www.stata.com/statalist/archive/2003-04/msg00411.html) solutions work either. Do you know an automatic way to obtain this? Even a simple function like eliminating specific words from labels (getting rid of the `region==` bit) would work. I can't find anything like it.

Comment: "None of these solutions work either" (with a link): either those refer to a different problem or (in one case) they are related to what is offered as an answer of below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Loop over the variables and zap unwanted text from the label each time. This basic functionality is documented at `help macro` and in the corresponding manual entry.

```
foreach v of var region_* { 
    local lbl : var label `v' 
    local lbl : subinstr local lbl "region==" "", all 
    local lbl = trim("`lbl'") 
    label var `v' "`lbl'" 
}
```

For a canned solution, see `labvarch` from `labutil` on SSC, which you can install with

```
ssc inst labutil
```

Comment: Kudos for `labutil`, and `labnoeq` in particular! I'm actually surprised that tabulate does not include an extra option that automatically deletes the `oldvar==` bit. It would be super handy.